# How to define "up" and "down" trends in R?

Tags: r

Let say I have the simplest data with "x" and "y" as input and output data.

How it's possible to define "up" and "down" trends in this data by using R functions and models. The value could be negative for the "down" trend [-1, 0), and positive for the "up" trend (0, 1]. I assume that for this test trend should be "down".

```
x <- c(1:8)  
y <- c(99, 104, 108, 100, 86, 64, 35, 15)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, y)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your sample data might have a clear direction but it's hard to come up with something that will work for every possible data set. Not all trends are linear or always in one direction. You could try a linear regression and estimate the slope of your line but it's unclear how you would scale those values to the 0,1 range. Since this doesn't seem to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow, maybe you should first ask for statistical advice on [stats.se] for suggestions on how to model your data.

Comment: Actually maybe you just want the correlation: `cor(x,y)`. That is scaled between -1 and 1 and also generally describes the strength and direction of the linear relationship between the variables.

Comment: In my real case one of the variable is "date", and another one is "numeric" value.

Comment: you should be able to transform date to numeric and use cor anyway

Comment: Have you considered ARIMA, which can account for trends and seasonality?

Comment: ARIMA is maybe for big data sets - i have small

Comment: Voting to close as "needs details or clarity". There have already been a couple of useful suggestions in comments but they have not been accepted. the OP has indicated that his example is not realistic.

Comment: @IRTFM This is a demo example, the real data can not be shared here. What I tried to ask is about approaches, and it seems the workable is using the sign of b1 coefficient.